# Multiple hdmi input screens on one monitor

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, hdmi

I've been building a robot for about a month now, and I always find it irritating to unplug my keyboard, mouse, plug it into the pi, and then switch the monitor to it. Is there any way to display a second HDMI input on windows? Like anydesk, but instead of opening someone else's screen, maybe it can open a second input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use VNC Viewer. You could also get an HDMI switch. There are also monitors with multiple inputs.